# Origin of Kiddush in Shul

Tags: shabbat

I'm not talking about reciting kiddush as part of Friday night maariv. I'm talking about having a kiddush in shul. I tried researching and couldn't find anything. Does anyone know what is the earliest mention of having a kiddush in shul after davening on Shabbos? Also what is the source for a Shabbos Mevarchim Kiddush?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think these things have sources? Is there a source for eating bagels on Sunday morning?

Comment: I would look in the historical books written by Jenna Weissman Joselit or a similar professor of American Jewish history for this answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm assuming that when synagogues first started they were not having a kiddush after musaf from day one. It had to start at a certain point in history.

Comment: A wonderful assumption. I still don't understand why you'd ask "what is the source for a Shabbos Mevarchim Kiddush?" as if you expect that to have a "source"

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm trying to determine if a Shabbos Mevarchim kiddush was something that was done in antiquity or if it is something 20th American Jews invented. Was it it done in pre-war Europe? Do Sephardim have any such tradition etc?